# Using jquery to link characters in a form to images in mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, image

Amateur novice here, so many thanks in advance for any help. I'm going crazy here.

I'm trying to develop a jquery script to search mysql via php for images stored in my database. User would type a word in an input field. Each *character* entered in that word returns a separate piece of artwork (e.g, type f-l-o-w-e-r and get six corresponding images). With some help, I got the php script working ok with a regular html form. But now that I've tried adding the jquery part, everything connects OK and seems to run the wayI want, but instead of images, I only get empty boxes with the 'broken image' icon.

I'm attaching the basic scripting of the find.php page below. After that, is the index.php page with the jquery. Any thoughts deeply appreciated...

```
$lettertype = str_split($lettertype);  
$lettertype = "'" . implode("','", $lettertype) . "'";   
$query = "SELECT * FROM Photos WHERE letter IN ($lettertype)"; 
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) 
      or    die ("No good");    
$alpharray = array(); 
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
         {
           $alpharray[$row['search_term']][] = $row; //
         }
       foreach(str_split($_POST['search_term']) as $alpha)
         {      
         echo "<a href='link.com'>
         <img src='../delete/images/{$alpharray[$alpha][0]['imagePath']}' width='100' height='140'/></a>";  
         }
```

And then the index.php...

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#search_results").slideUp(); 
    $("#search_button").click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        ajax_search(); 
    }); 
    $("#search_term").keyup(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        ajax_search(); 
    }); 

}); 
function ajax_search(){ 
  $("#search_results").show(); 
  var search_val=$("#search_term").val(); 
  $.post("./find.php", {search_term : search_val}, function(data){
   if (data.length>0){ 
     $("#search_results").html(data); 
   } 
  }) 
} 
</script>

<title>Welcome!</title> 
</head> 

<body> 
<h1>Search here</h1> 
    <form id="searchform" method="post"> 
<div> 
        <label for="search_term">Search</label> 
        <input type="text" name="search_term" id="search_term" /> 
<input type="submit" value="search" id="search_button" /> 
</div> 
    </form> 
    <div id="search_results"></div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the generated source (using something like FireBug) to see what the URLs to the images look like? If you're getting the broken image icon, it's most likely a mistake in the URL that's being generated for each image.

Comment: Your img src looks a little odd as is starts with two dots, "..delete/images".  Usually ".." us used to move up a directory and a "/" usually follows.  Of course it doesn't have to work like that and you may really have a directory relative to the delivered page called "..delete".

Comment: Hi, thanks for the thoughts. I do have a folder named delete in which the script files and images folder are located. Is this the problem maybe?

Comment: Todd, thanks. The images are saved in a folder as jpg files that I'm accessing with the scripts so I'm not sure I get the URL issue. Maybe you can help me understand?

Comment: I get this message when I try to fire it up: "Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined." I'm running everything on my local computer using MAMP. I'm guessing this is part of the issue. Tips or direction to resources I could use to educate myself appreciated. Maybe should post as new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The src attribute of `<img>` is always relative to the URL of the actual page the webbrowser sees. 
Example:
`www.example.com/test/index.php` contains an `<img>` with `src=../image.jpg` means the webbrowser tries to load `www.example.com/image.jpg`

So if your index.php lies in `/` (e.g. www.example.com/index.php), it is likely that referring to an image in `../delete` won't work as the server doesn't allow accessing thing outside its webroot.

In any case however, if you want to access the parent directory, you need to put in a `../` (not only `..`)

For your script this would mean:

```php
foreach(str_split($_POST['search_term']) as $alpha)
     {      
     echo "<a href='link.com'>
     <img src='../delete/images/{$alpharray[$alpha][0]['imagePath']}' width='100' height='140'/></a>";  
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab at it. Really appreciate it. Unfortunately it's something else that's going wrong. The missing / was a residual typo from me playing around with it too much. Sorry for the confusion. It didn't work even when I had the pathway right.